# removing trailing slash not working htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using shared hosting so not sure if there's some weird rule imeplemented but basically I've tried the rule everyone recommends which is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# removes trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

With no rules at all, the server seems to force a direct to a trailing slash. Even if I add this rule, it stills redirect to trailing slash. I want to force redirect to no trailing slash.

How do I debug this? All the files are static html, no php.

my site is also behind cloudflare if that matters and I am testing with curl

edit:
this is working to prevent no trailing slash from redirecting, but it doesn't make trailing slash redirect to no trailing slash. Also I'm not able to combine it with force www.

```
DirectorySlash Off

#removing trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST_FILENAME} \ /(.*)/(\ |$|\?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]

# internally add the slash back
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Make sure you are using ```RewriteEngine On``` before the rewrite rules.

Comment: it is on I just didn't include it, not sure what you mean by make a rewrite rule, i already have rewrite rules and they are not giving me the expected results

Comment: I understand, I don't mean it wrong. Sorry. I was in a rush, so I commented that. @user12341234 sorry.

Comment: I am unable to solve this because you are internally adding the slash back. It just redirects endlessly. And, I will try to find another way to internally add the slash back.